# Querying database with 2 loops gives wrong result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a website panel that is going to list break-in attempts to the admin panel. When I try to list them all, it only shows the first one out of 10.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
    include("xxxxxxxxx.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('[MYSQLI ERROR] '.mysqli_error($link));
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $ip = $row['ip'];
      $date = $row['date'];
      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM xxxxxx WHERE ip='".$ip."'";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die('[MYSQLI ERROR] '.mysqli_error($link));
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $userid .= ";".$row['id'];
        $user .= ";".$row['name'];
      }
      $userids = explode($userid, ";");
      $users = explode($user, ";");
      for($i=1;$i<=count($users);$i++) {
        $userinfo .= "<a href=\"xxx.php?id=".$userids[$i]."\">".$users[$i]."</a><br/>";
      }
      echo "
        <tr>
          <td>".$date."</td>
          <td>".$ip."</td>
          <td>".$userinfo."</td>
        </tr>
      ";
    }
  ?>
```

Why isn't it working?

And before you ask why I am starting at 1 in the for() loop, it is because the first one will be "" and I don't need that result displayed.

Comment: Please check your syntax and logical errors in the future before asking a question. It is obvious that you are replacing $row and using first resource for second loop. Every question you post here takes time of somebody else and in order to respect that it is a good idea to work on your code yourself a little bit more before posting here... That is why i down voted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `while` loop exhausts the result of the first query (`$result`) instead of iterating over the result of the second query (`$result2`) like it's supposed to.

In short, replace this block:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $userid .= ";".$row['id'];
  $user .= ";".$row['name'];
}
```

With:

```
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { // Note the usage of $result2.
  $userid .= ";".$row2['id'];
  $user .= ";".$row2['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for $result2 but the $row also needs to be $row2
+1
Thanks

Comment: `$row` is a temporary variable that isn't used afterwards, so you could probably get away with reusing it, but you're right - having another variable is more elegant. Edited.

Comment: $row would interfere with the previous loop since it is inside of the other loop wouldn't it?

Comment: It gets overridden every iteration anyway, so it shouldn't really matter (although, again, it is clearer to have another variable for the inner loop).

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 while loop which use $row as the variable.

Change the second loop to use a different variable name will fix it

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I can accept the answer in 11 minutes and I plan on doing so. Also, I realized that the mysqli_fetch_assoc() function in the second while loop was using the first result. :D Again, thanks for helping out.